# converting an array into array of arrays of N size but with a maximum sub array size

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, split

I am trying to convert an array into equal sized arrays of *n* length, however, the amount of arrays cannot exceed the size of *o*.
where an array cannot be split into *n* length without exceeding *o* array of arrays then *n* can increase to accommodate reducing the number of array of arrays to *o*.
Any non *n* sized arrays should be shifted to the start of the array of arrays.
optionally each element should be able to be concatenated

Note: I am using numbers for visualisation of the question, but the elements are objects.

for example: 
note array parenthesises are {}, [], () in these examples for easier visualisation

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5], n = 2, o = 15
var shouldOutput = [{0,1},{2,3},{4,5},{6,7},{8,9},{0,1},{2,3},{4,5}]

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5], n = 2, o = 15
var shouldOutput = [{1},{2,3},{4,5},{6,7},{8,9},{0,1},{2,3},{4,5}]

var arr = [01,23,45,67,89,01,23,45,67,89,01,23,45,67,89,01,23], n = 2, o = 15, concatenate = true 
var shouldOutput = [({01})({2345})({6789})({0123})({4567})({8901})({2345})({6789})({0123})]
```

so far I have the following code which will correctly generate array of arrays with *n* length and correctly pushes any remainder elements to the start of the array but I am unsure how to progress to limiting the array of arrays length to *o* length.

```
let getArrChunks = function (arr, n, o, joinStr) {
    let ret = [];
    let max = Math.floor(arr.length / n);
    if ((arr.length % n) > 0) max++;
    for (let i = arr.length - n; i > -n; i -= n) {
        ret[(max--)-1] = joinStr === undefined ? arr.splice(i, n) : arr.splice(i, n).join(joinStr);
    }
    return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size for each sub array (except maybe the first) is the result of this expression:

```
Math.max(n, Math.ceil(arr.length / o))
```

If the above expression is re-assigned to *n*, then the size of the *first* subarray is:

```
arr.length % n
```

...except if that expression is zero, in that case the first sub array has the same size as the others, i.e. *n*

Used in this demo:

```js
const getArrChunks = function (arr, n, o, joinStr) {
    n = Math.max(n, Math.ceil(arr.length / o)); // n is here increased if necessary
    const first = arr.slice(0, arr.length % n);
    const ret = first.length ? [joinStr === undefined ? first : first.join(joinStr)] : [];
    for (let i = first.length; i < arr.length; i += n) {
        ret.push(joinStr === undefined ? arr.slice(i, i+n) : arr.slice(i, i+n).join(joinStr));
    }
    return ret;
};

console.log(getArrChunks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 2, 3));
```

Note that there is no call to `splice`, but to `slice`. This way the given input array is not mutated.

Comment: Your solution looks better then my test :-D. But there is maybe one error, when joinStr is defined, the first value (overlapping) is an array and not a string:

    console.log(getArrChunks([01, 23, 45, 67, 89, 01, 23, 45, 67, 89, 01, 23, 45, 67, 89, 01, 23], 2, 5, ','));
    
    Should output? ["1", "23,45,67,89", "1,23,45,67", "89,1,23,45", "67,89,1,23"]
    
   Outputing:  [Array(1), "23,45,67,89", "1,23,45,67", "89,1,23,45", "67,89,1,23"]

Comment: Ah yes, forgot to apply the join logic in the first element. That's updated now.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is limit the length of the array, you can use [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
ret = ret.splice(0, o);
return ret;
```

Full code:

```
let getArrChunks = function (arr, n, o, joinStr) {
    let ret = [];
    let max = Math.floor(arr.length / n);
    if ((arr.length % n) > 0) max++;
    for (let i = arr.length - n; i > -n; i -= n) {
        ret[(max--)-1] = joinStr === undefined ? arr.splice(i, n) : arr.splice(i, n).join(joinStr);
    }
    ret = ret.splice(0, o);
    return ret;
};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however, i need to keep all elements but reduce the output elements to a maximum of *o* by increasing *n* to accommodate for this.